# Angular Binding как лучше

Tags: angular, angular2, binding, angular4, angular5

Скажите какой способ лучше подходит для отслеживания изменений переменной в Angular.

1. `<img [src]="img" alt="">`
2. `<img src="{{img}}" alt="">`

Предполагается что переменная `img` может в любой момент поменять свое значение.

Какой способ правильнее и почему? Спасибо!

PS: только начинаю изучать Angular, и надеюсь понятно объяснил

Answer (score 1):

Работать будет в обоих вариантах, но тут есть концептуальный нюанс - `<img [src]="img" alt="">` использует привязку к свойству, а `<img src="{{img}}" alt="">` - это интерполяция строки.
Для указания src (да и вообще любого строкового параметра) они подходят оба ([а дока ангуляра вообще рекомендует использовать интерполяцию в целях упрощения чтения разметки](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding#property-binding-and-interpolation)), но мне для единобразия проще придерживаться property binding повсеместно, а интерполяцию использовать для заполнения содержимого тегов в разметке.